# prove homomorphic image has order 4

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $20$ show that $G$ has homomorphic image of order $4$.

From Cauchy theorem we have elements $a,b \in G$ of orders $2,5$ respectively then

from first isomorphic theorem homomorphic image is isomorphic with $G/kerf$ for some homomorphism $f:G \to im(f)$

so if $kerf=<b>$ then will be ok but to show that I need $<b>$ is normal subgroup of $G$ and I have some problems with that

Answer (score 1):

$G/\langle b\rangle$ is such a homomorphic image. The subgroup generated by $b$ is normal by the Sylow's theorems. Indeed the number $n$ of subgroups of order $5$ is congruent to $1\mod 5$, and a divisor of $20/5=4$. Hence $n=1$, which proves the subgroup is normal.

Comment: can this problem be solved without sylow's theorem ?

Comment: I don't know. Sylow's theorems are not part of your curriculum?

Comment: unfortunately already not, but this problem is from 2009 exam so maybe then sylow was at syllabus